# I want to calculate this time Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

`$array = [ '00:09:45', '00:50:05', '00:01:05', ]`

I tried this calculating time but it is not working.

Comment: That is not a calculation, it's an array of String representations of Time... Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75149346/edit) and include more details; your question doesn't make any sense as currently written, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that by calculate he meant addition.
(Nuances related to translation). Below is an example function in Laravel that adds these times from an array. You should use Carbon for this purpose.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

function addTimes($times) {
    $totalTime = Carbon::createFromTime(0, 0, 0);
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
        $totalTime->addSeconds($time->secondsSinceMidnight());
    }
    return $totalTime;
}

$times = [ '00:09:45', '00:50:05', '00:01:05', ];
$totalTime = addTimes($times);

echo $totalTime->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want sum the durations of time. We can transform it in a collection and reduce it by adding the times.

```
use Carbon/Carbon;

$array = collect(['12:09:45', '11:50:05', '07:01:05']);
$total = $array->reduce(function ($time, $timeNext){
    $carbonTimeNext = new Carbon($timeNext);
    $time->addHours($carbonTimeNext->format('H'))
        ->addMinutes($carbonTimeNext->format('i'))
        ->addSeconds($carbonTimeNext->format('s'));
    return $time;
}, new Carbon('00:00:00'));

echo $total->shortAbsoluteDiffForHumans(new Carbon('00:00:00'), 6);

//output: 1d 7h 55s
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing times can be done using Carbon like so (less is more):

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
$times = ['00:09:45', '00:50:05', '00:01:05'];

$time = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(array_reduce($times, function($sum, $item) {
    return $sum + Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0)->setTimeFromTimeString($item)->timestamp;
}));
```

Note: the resulting `$time` variable is a Carbon date from *unix time = 0* with the times added from your array.

The sum of seconds from your array can thus be retrieved using the `timestamp` property, which is the amount of seconds since the start of the unix epoch:

```php
$sumSeconds = $time->timestamp;
// 3655
```

Displaying it as a string goes as follows:

```php
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
$str = $time->diffForHumans(Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0), CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, false, 2);
// "1 hour 55 seconds"
```